# How to temporarily disable the "java" command in cmd

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

I have a situation where I need to test a program with and without Java "installed". Instead of uninstalling and reinstalling for each test, I figured it would be ideal if I could simply disable the "java" command from working in cmd as this is the way the program determines if Java is installed. Is there an easy way to do this? I have tried removing any mentions of Java from the Environment variables (I'm on Windows 10 Education), but this does not seem to have had any effect. I am okay with hacky solutions as I just need this for my own quick tests on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the location of the java executabe with

```
c:\>  where java
```

This may return multiple instances of `java.exe` in different directories of your PATH. Remove all returned directories from the PATH and **restart your cmd.exe**, because cmd will pick up changes in the environment variables only after it is restarted.

Comment: thank you! where java turned up 2 directories, and it would seem I had missed one, additionally I am using the windows terminal application and relaunching a new cmd window does not actually restart cmd.exe it seems!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the paths of java from the environment variables(from user variables and System variables) then start cmd and type `java`, it should be unrecognised.